# Stacks with custom vector types

Tags: c++, vector, stack

I have a type `Block`, which is a vector of 4 integers.

```
typedef vector<int> Block;
```

I have a vector of `Block`s.

```
vector<Block> blockCollection
```

Now, let's say I want to sort/search these Blocks in some arbitrary function. To do this I utilize a stack:

```
stack<Block> blockStack;
```

Where each `Block` in `blockStack` is a vector of 4 integers. How do I access or display each element in `blockStack`?

Comment: A stack is a last-in-first-out structure. Why do you need to use a stack?

Comment: What about simply using blockStack[x][y]?

Comment: @arc_lupus `std::stack` has no `operator[]`.

Comment: @cdhowie: Oops, thanks, wrong idea from myself...

Comment: you created a complex hierarchy, but the access is really simple. on each level, you use the appropriate access method... it's unclear what you're asking. don't you know how you can access elements of a stack or a vector?

Comment: Regarding the stack: if you need to access anything but the top element by index, you may be choosing the wrong structure.

Comment: If you know that it's always 4 integers you might want to make it a `std::array<int,4>` or your own data type instead of a vector, since you seem to have enough indirection already.

Comment: Don't use `std::stack` or the other "container adapters" such as `std::queue`. Apart from toy problems, they are too restrictive. Use the real data structures directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stacks are intended for use in applications where you *only* add values to one side of a container and *only* access the top element on that same side of the container. Looking at [the functions available to the stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/) should give you a good idea why this is the case - you are very limited with regard to insertion and access operations. If your program needs more functionality than this, then a stack probably isn't a good choice of data structure.

I would suggest that you use a `std::vector` instead. You have two methods to access the contents of a `std::vector`: the subscript operator `[]`, and the member function `at()` (the latter of which will throw an error if the requested index is out of bounds). We also have an easy way to iterate over a `std::vector` using a for loop.

If not using C++11:

```
for(vector<vector<Block>>::iterator iter = myVector.begin(); iter != myVector.end(); ++iter)
{
    //do stuff to iter
}
```

Using C++11 makes the syntax simpler:

```
for(auto value : myVector)    //read-only. to alter value, change to auto&
{
    //do stuff to value
}
```

Comment: Good point - they *are* talking about accessing all the contained values. Might as well add it on...